# Click outside area to close mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, toggle

I have two questions.

Q.1

I have a WordPress website and I want the mobile menu to be closed if someone clicks outside the menu anywhere on the page.

Currently, it works on the hamburger menu.

Q.2

This is a single-page website. If someone clicks on the menu it scrolls.

I want to add the behaviour if someone clicks on the mobile menu then it scrolls(it is working right now) and hide the menu (not working).

You can check the website link where I have the problem.

https://www.dezigneronline.net/361apps/

Given below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* =================
     Menu Mobile
     =================== */
    $('.ct-main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children').append('<span class="ct-menu-toggle far fac-angle-right"></span>');
    $('.ct-menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggle-open');
        $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu, > .children').toggleClass('submenu-open');
        $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu, > .children').slideToggle();
    });

    /* =================
     Menu Popup
     =================== */
    $('.ct-main-menu-popup li.menu-item-has-children > a').after('<span class="ct-menu-toggle"></span>');
    $('.ct-main-menu-popup .ct-menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggle-open');
        $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu, > .children').toggleClass('submenu-open');
        $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu, > .children').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.ct-menu-popup').on('click', function () {
        $('body').addClass('ov-hidden');
        $(this).parents('body').find('.ct-header-popup-wrap').toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.ct-menu-close').on('click', function () {
        $('body').removeClass('ov-hidden');
        $(this).parents('body').find('.ct-header-popup-wrap').toggleClass('open');
    });
    
    $("#ct-menu-mobile .open-menu").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        $('.ct-header-navigation').toggleClass('navigation-open');
    });

    $(".ct-menu-close").on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('.header-navigation').removeClass('navigation-open');
        $('.ct-menu-overlay').removeClass('active');
        $('#ct-menu-mobile .open-menu').removeClass('opened');
        $('body').removeClass('ov-hidden');
    });

    $(".ct-menu-overlay").on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('#header-main').find('.header-navigation').removeClass('navigation-open');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#ct-menu-mobile .open-menu').removeClass('opened');
        $('.header-navigation').removeClass('navigation-open');
        $('body').removeClass('ov-hidden');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Regarding **Q1** use a simple click event on the whole body to close the menu, to prevent that from happening when you click inside the menu, use `stopPropagation` on your menu element

Comment: @Lapskaus Thanks for your reply. Could you please help me to update the code? I am not an expert in it.

Comment: Hi, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to handle a click on a parent that spans over the whole page to close the menu, that could be e.g.the `body` element. The problem: your menu is a child of the body and therefore will trigger the event too. To prevent that you would need to  `stopPropagation();` on the menu element, so that the click event does not bubble up the DOM and reaches your body.

Consider this simpliefied version to demonstrate the mechanic:

```js
$('body').not('.menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').hide();
});

$('.menu').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
body , html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

.menu{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</body>
```